# Rounding QSpinBox Background Color Corners

Tags: qt, qspinbox, qstylesheet

I'm developing a GUI in Qt 4.8 ( C++ being the base language ), and I have trouble stylizing a QSpinBox.

I'd like the widget to have a nice rounded border ( I've disabled the up and down buttons via Qt Creator ) using [Qt Style Sheets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html) and I manage to do it quite fine with the following code:

```
QSpinBox {
    color: white;
    selection-background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
```

However, as soon as I try to set a background color, whether by defining the *background* or *background-color* property, the **background color fills the entirety of the widget's rectangle**, making the widget quite ugly ( at this point, the white borders are still correctly rounded ).

```
QSpinBox {
    color: white;
    selection-background-color: black;
    background: blue;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
```

**I'd of course want the background-color rectangle to be rounded in the same way**. I've tried to play a bit with the *background-clip* and *background-origin* properties like that:

```
QFrame, QSpinBox {
        color: white;
        selection-background-color: black;
        background-origin: border;
        background-clip: border;
        border: 1px solid white;
        border-radius: 5px;
        text-align:center;
        padding-left: 2px;
        padding-top: 2px;
}
```

But nothing that I try seems to do the trick. Is there something I missed, or do wrong ?

Comment: Your CSS works for me using Qt5.5, maybe it was a bug in Qt4 ?

Comment: Maybe. The strange thing is that when I don't set a 'background', the default one assigned by Qt Creator does respect the rounded borders...

Comment: Not ideal but have you tried to change the colours through the QPalette instead of the style-sheet ?

Comment: Nope. I've sticked with ugly straight corners for the moment, but I'll give a try via QPalette. I'll update if I achieve anything with it, thanks for the suggestion !

Answer (score 1):

Use setAutoFillBackground(false);